# Rails, issue selecting by boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through a Rails tutorial, and have hit a wall I'm not sure if I missed a step. I have two models, both with a boolean called 'visible', but I can only select using it on one of the models. For reference here are my migrations

```
class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :subjects do |t|
      t.string "name"
      t.integer "position"
      t.boolean "visible", :default => false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :subjects
  end

end
```

And

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.integer "subject_id"
      t.string "name"
      t.string "permalink"
      t.integer "position"
      t.boolean "visible", :default => false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index("pages", "subject_id")
    add_index("pages", "permalink")
  end

  def down
    drop_table :pages
  end

end
```

Both have a t.boolean "visible", :default => false in them. And I can edit them and change that value fine. But if I say pull up a rails console and try...

This works fine:

```
Subject.visible
```

This gives me a NoMethodError: undefined method `visible':

```
Page.visible
```

During one point in the tutorial I had to change the line

```
@page.sections.visible.sorted.each
```

to

```
@page.sections.where(:visible => true).sorted.each
```

Which did work, but I have no idea WHY I had to do so

Link to project on GitHub if it helps
https://github.com/TaylorHuston/Rails_LyndaCMS

Comment: Did you run ```rake db:migrate``` after you created both migrations?

Comment: Yes. Those were early in the tutorial, and everything else works fine. I can even toggle visible on or off with a checkbox on a form if I need to.

<%= f.check_box(:visible) %>

Comment: The function visible is for an instance, not on the model.  Use Page.new.visible

Comment: Then why can I run it on the Subject model, and why did I have to change that line in the tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `visible` function is an instance function, so you have to use it on an instance of **Page**:

```
Page.new.visible
```

You were able to use it on **Subject** because you created a `scope :visible`, so you have one function for the instance and one for the Relation.

Comment: You are a genius. I wonder if I missed that step in the tutorial early on, or if the author forgot to mention it. In either case that worked, thanks!